# django non model form - use of meta to order fields of inherited form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to reorder the rendering of the fields of a standard django form. The form inherits from a base form and builds on that.

In a similar way to using `Meta` and `fields` to order and specify fields for a model form can this be used to reorder fields for an inherited form or what is the best way to achieve this?
(eg something like:)

```
class SignupForm(allauthforms.SignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['email', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a `Meta` class only works for `ModelForm`s and won't have any effect for regular `Form` classes.

If you are using Django 1.9 or newer, you can define a [field_order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.field_order) attribute

```
class SignupForm(allauthforms.SignupForm):
    field_order = ['email', 'password2']
```

For older versions of Django, you would have to change the fields attribute.

```
class SignupForm(allauthforms.SignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields = OrderedDict([
            ('email', self.fields['email']),
            ('password2', self.fields['password2'])
        ])
```

Alternatively, you can just list the individual form fields in the order you want in your template.

Answer (score 1):

When rendering a form you can use Form.field_order. It is available since django 1.9

All you have to do is pass a list, with ordered field names.